# RenderSection ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

In ASP.NET Core 6, does `@RenderSection` always work on the name that you give to your section? Could it be like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/layout.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("scriptsNav_menu", required: false)
</html>
```

```
@section ScriptsNav_menu {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/contacts.js"></script>
}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>    Contacts</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I didn't try it myself, to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.rendersection?view=aspnetcore-7.0) about the `RenderSection`

> In layout pages, renders the content of the section named `name`.

> `required` indicates if this section must be rendered.

So when your view `<h2>Contacts</h2>` containing `@section ScriptsNav_menu` is loaded, you will see `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/layout.js"></script>` like screenshot below.

[image]

But when you visit another view which doesn't contain `@section ScriptsNav_menu`, the `~/lib/layout.js` won't load.

[image]

While set `required` to true, and visit Privacy page again I get error below which means the script will always be loaded.

[image]